# Turn function z(x,y) into list of ordered triples

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm hoping to plot multiple sets of data on the same axes using `ListPointPlot3D`.

One of my data sets is parameterized by a single variable:

```
firstDataSet = Table[ {x_func[t], y_func[t], z_func[t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.01} ]
```

The other is a surface requiring two:

```
secondDataSet = Table[ {x, y, z_func_2[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.01}, {y, -1, 1, 0.01} ]
```

However, while the first gives me a list of ordered triples, the second gives me a list of *lists of* ordered triples.

What's the most idiomatic way to get a list of ordered triples for my second data set? I'm not very familiar with Mathematica, but generating a list of lists and then flattening it feels somewhat hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really see no problem with using `Flatten`, but here's another way to do it.

```
{First@#, Last@#, z_func_2@@#} & /@ Tuples[Range[-1, 1, 0.01], 2];
```

Of course this one requires you be comfortable with Mathematica's [pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and with [function mapping](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html). If you are worried about performance, you could implement this a bunch of different ways and hit them all with the `Timing` function to see which goes fastest (because I suppose that if it runs fast, then it's the least *hacky*).

```
r = Range[-1, 1, 0.01];
f[pair_] := {First@pair, Last@pair, z_func_2@@pair};

Flatten@Table[{x, y, z_func_2[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.01}, {y, -1, 1, 0.01}] // Timing
f /@ Tuples[r, 2] // Timing
Flatten@Outer[f, r, r] // Timing
```

(Note that I didn't check that this code runs alright; I don't have Mathematica installed on my current computer)